# Running commands inside the same script as different users

Tags: bash, permissions, users, root

I have a bizarre situation where I need to run a script where *some* commands are ran as `root` and other commands are ran as non-root (an `ubuntu` user). Under the hood this is a script that AWS EC2 is running in the background for me, and its a script that provisions new nodes/instances/VMs for me when they spin up automatically.

I know I can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u ubuntu -i <<'EOF'

cmd1
cmd2
cmd3

EOF
```

However, the nature of this script, I actually need to jump back and forth between `root` and `ubuntu` several times. Is it possible to do this? To run a set of commands in a script as User 1, then run a subsequent set of commands as User 2 (same script) and then run the final set of commands back as User 1 again? If so, how? And if not, just curious, why?!

Comment: You already have to the answer. Use `sudo -u user` for the lines that need to run as other users. Otherwise, they'll run as the user executing the script.

Comment: This sounds like the kind of complexity in server provisioning that configuration managers like Ansible, Chef, Puppet, and Saltstack (and others) were designed for.  They can run some commands as root and others as different users; they can invoke the configurations in the right sequence to avoid dependency trouble; and they can be fully automatic when your use case involves AWS Autoscale launching a replacement server because the original server's hardware went bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Tried with this worked fine

I am running this script as root

#!/bin/bash
su praveen <<'EOF'  ====> it will switch to praveen user and executes command
whoami
w
exit        ===> here it will exits and go back to root user
EOF
whoami    ====> here its running whoami command as root user
```